# Save/Read Custom Arraylist in Sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, listmodel

I'm working on a app where you can save and read homeworks, for the "undone" progress I want to save the Arraylist, where I saved all homeworks, in the Shared Preferences. I hope you know what I mean, thanks in advance :)

**HausaufgabenActivity.java:**

```
    ArrayList<Hausaufgabe> hausaufgabeList = new ArrayList<Hausaufgabe>();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    if(!hausaufgabeList.contains(ha)){
       hausaufgabeList.add(ha);
    }
    //Set the values
    Set<Hausaufgabe> set = new HashSet<Hausaufgabe>();
    set.addAll(hausaufgabeList);
    editor.putString("AllHomeworks", set);
    editor.commit();
```

**Hausaufgabe.java:**

```
public Hausaufgabe(String beschreibung, String DeviceID, String Abgabedatum, String Fach, String Erstellungsdatum){
    super();
    this.beschreibung = beschreibung;
    this.DeviceID = DeviceID;
    this.Abgabedatum = Abgabedatum;
    this.Fach = Fach;
    this.Erstellungsdatum = Erstellungsdatum;
}


public String getBeschreibung() {
    return beschreibung;
}

public String getAbgabedatum() {
    return Abgabedatum;
}

public String getFach() {
    return Fach;
}

public String getDeviceID() {
    return DeviceID;
}

public String getErstellungsdatum() {
    return Erstellungsdatum;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try :

```
Set<Hausaufgabe> set = new HashSet<Hausaufgabe>();
set.addAll(hausaufgabeList);
editor.putStringSet("AllHomeworks", set);
editor.commit();
```

where

```
editor.putString("AllHomeworks", set);   -> editor.putStringSet("AllHomeworks", set);
```

Comment: Tried it, put it says: editor.putSTRINGset(...), i would need something like editor.putHausaufgabeSet(...)

Comment: Okay, didn't noticed that it wasn't String in HashSet :D 
You should try to serialize it. Then save serialized object as string in SharedPreference

Comment: https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java

Then 
     mSpEditor.putString("AllHomeworks" ObjectSerializer.serialize(hausaufgabeList));

Comment: what do you mean with serialize? I serialize an Arraylist into a string?

Comment: and how will I get a Arraylist out of this?

Comment: By using     ArrayList<Hausaufgabe> hausaufgabeList = (ArrayList<Hausaufgabe> hausaufgabeList = ) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(yourSerializedString)